# Why only considering arcs in the positive direction when seating people in a ring?

Tags: probability

Here is part of problem 17 ch.2 from Feller's Probability:

> If n men, among whom are A and B, stand in a circular ring, show that the probability that there will be exactly r men between A and B is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. (Only consider the arc from A to B in the positive direction).

I believe, from the hint, the argument is supposed to go like this: There are n choices for A, one choice for B if only considering the positive direction, and (n-2)! choices for the rest of the men. If we are only concerned with adjacencies, not seat numbers, we must also divide by n. So there are (n-2)! ways for A and B to have exactly r people between them up to adjacencies, and (n-1)! ways to sit n people in a circle up to adjacencies, hence the desired probability is $\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-1)!} =  \frac{1}{n-1}$.

What I don't understand is why we are only considering arcs in the positive direction.

Comment: Because the author asked you to interpret the question that way.

Comment: Note that whatever chair A sits in, there are $n-1$ equally likely positions for B, and therefore $r=0,1,2,\dots,n-2$ are equally likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only considering cases in the positive corrections, per the hint, stops the answer from duplicating the possible lay outs but forgetting to account for mirrored positions.

The goal is to determine the probability that r individuals are positioned between A and B. Since n positions are available, after A assumes a position there are n-1 places B can be. Adding B to the circle, abiding by the hint, r will range from 0 to n-2.  With the hint, we are explicitly told to ignore that if r individuals are positioned between A and B going in the positive direction, than (n-2-r) individuals are positioned between A and B in the negative direction. Consider x, where x = n-2-r; adjust the positions of the individuals around the circle. Now, there are x individuals between A and B in the positive direction, with r individuals between A and B in the negative direction. This reflects two possible lay outs where r individuals are positioned between A and B.